# Does iOS report usage in megabytes or mebibytes?

Tags: ios, settings, terminology, statistics

When looking at usage stats in iOS (data sent/received), are the megabytes/gigabytes in base-10 or base-2?

The docs are not entirely conclusive (since it doesn't address usage specifically) but suggests base-2 is used for iOS device capacities.

So which is it?

Answer (score 3):

I wasn't able to find conclusive documentation on this so [I tested it](http://blog.wassupy.com/2012/12/does-ios-report-usage-in-mebibytes-or.html). **I found that iOS uses the base-10 definition** when showing usage.

That is, if you send a large file, say 10 mebibytes (10 × 2<sup>20</sup>, or 10485760 bytes), it will report it in megabytes, counting a megabyte as 1,000,000 bytes (not 1,048,576 bytes).

So that 10 MB, shows up as 10.4 MB:

[image: 10mb usage]

(I'm *not* suggesting that there's anything nefarious going on here related to billing or data limits.)